# file_get_contents() "failed to open stream: Network is unreachable" error on valid link

Tags: php, https, get, youtube-api, file-get-contents

There's an extremely simple example of using Youtube API in php that somehow fails to work in my case, and I couldn't find a definitive solution for.

I desire to use the Youtube API without any wrapper, by myself, to get data of videos. The following `search:list` query works perfectly when I try accessing it from within by browser (as a link), but in php, I get that error when I try the same.

```
        $apikey_YT = <my API key>;
        $ytrequrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?".
                "part=snippet".
                "&maxResults=50".
                "&q=doom".
                "&relatedToVideoId=h8j2zj-A5tE".
                "&type=video".
                "&key=${apikey_YT}";

        $result = file_get_contents($ytrequrl);
        var_dump($result);
```

The potential issues were URL encoding, or allowing `allow-url-fopen`, but neither seemed to help in my case: the former actually gave a new error message: `No such file or directory`.

What can I do?

Comment: `${apikey_YT}`? variable variable? Might wanna loose the `{` and `}`

Comment: @Xorifelse a php-specific syntax for putting variable values into strings without breaking them with `"."` - I tested the string itself multiple times and it works properly. But may worth a try.

Comment: @Xorifelse did it, but no change happened.

Comment: Have you tried a simple [tag:curl] request?

Comment: And Zoltan, that "specific" syntax is used to define variable variables in PHP. To simply add a value to a `"string"` you can just do `"$var"` or `"{$var['index']}"`.

Comment: @Xorifelse oh, I'm sorry then, can't exactly remember where did I get the idea. Anyway, haven't tried curl yet, I wanted to solve the issue without it, in case my host doesn't support curl.

Comment: @Xorifelse tried with curl, now I get a "connection refused" error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139082/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-zoltan-schmidt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this. Might be your formatting.
This works for me.

```
$ytrequrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=doom&relatedToVideoId=h8j2zj-A5tE&type=video&key='.$apikey_YT;

$info= file_get_contents($ytrequrl);
$info= json_decode($info, true);

print("<pre>".print_r($info,true)."</pre>");
```