# Latest youtube video from specific playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'd like to display latest uploaded video from the specific playlist from youtube on my site, and I couldn't find info how to do that on YT API documentation pages, any tips?
Do note that playlist I'm pulling video from is not mine, but it's public playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a call to `playlistItems` will give you the videos in order of last in , first out. So last one added should be at node '0', or first in list.

If however that is not the case, the best way to make sure is to also do a published check.
This is in [items] => [`node number`] => [snippet] => [publishedAt]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I'm not sure how to setup simple YT API call and get json results, if that's how this should work? I'm trying to find this info in their documentation, but I'm somehow lost.

Comment: Firstly, all responses from the YouTube api are in a JSON format. As to using it, you can do a search here on stackoverflow for "json decode" and specify if needed, a language like php or javascript. There are plenty of them here. As for the call to youtube, simplist way is to use the "restfull" api. I give an example in this post using php. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029811/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-network-is-unreachable-error-on-val/43031058#43031058

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful got it!